Execution process behind chaining of primitives as objects in Kotlin
I was learning Kotlin when I encountered this operation
    3.5.plus(4)
    res0: kotlin.Double = 7.5

its result is 7.5
I am trying for the last 1 day to understand whats the process behind this result.
I also searched for answers for similar questions, but I wasnt able to get an outcome.
I am a beginner to understanding kotlin and its working. Hoping the community can give an answer to this question and help this poor soul :.

I am not expecting this, I am expecting more like 12

What is confusing for you, what is your expected result? Why do you expect 12? 3.5 + 4 is 7.5 after all.

I confused . to be of a functional call operation. since they are mentioning about calling objects as primitives.

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html

3.5 is a type Double and plus() is the operator + so what your are doing is 3.5 + 4 and that equals 7.5. You can also write the same as 3.5 + 4

ok. that was a Silly one. Thanks Stephan. :)
